# How to correctly utilize Zip Code entity for DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, zipcode

I'm currently trying to use the built in entity '@sys.zip-code' from DialogFlow (formerly API.AI) for capturing Zip Codes.  However so far it does not seem to recognize any actual zipcodes except those which I explicitly set through training.  It also does not recognize the '5 digit' pattern as a possible match if @sys.phone-numbers is used in another intent (ex: 54545 gets recognized as a phone number, rather than a zip).

Should I upload a list of known zipcodes through the training section to get this working?  Or is there something I'm missing from the built in functionality?  Haven't seen a ton of info online on how to best utilize this entity, so figured I'd ask here before coming up with a custom solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to prompt a user when the bot says something like   "could I get your name and zip code? ".The intent which i have  created contains multiple combinations of “User says”.They are as below

1. @"@sys.given-name @sys.zip-code"
2. @"@sys.zip-code @sys.given-name"
3. @"@sys.given-name"
4. @"@sys.zip-code"
   and I also have required Parameters setup to pick these values with prompt messages.

So I have attached a picture for this which i have iterated

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping to do this without the need to have a prompt.